# matplotlib only shows labels for every other year in data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data from a dataframe object read from a file, it plots the data however on the x-axis it only shows years in intervals of 2. My code

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


#read data 
topics_df = pd.read_csv("../myData/topicsData.csv")
print(topics_df)

print("\n")
print(topics_df.Sexeducation)
print(topics_df.Year)
plt.bar(topics_df.Year, topics_df.Sexeducation, color="blue", width=0.4)
plt.show()
```

mydate for the topics_df dataframe object:

```
   Year  Sexeducation  Plants  DigestiveSystem  BreathingSystem  Diseases
0  2000             2       3                4                5         7
1  2001             5       7                1                3         1
2  2002             3       1                4                1         3
3  2003             9       8                1                5         6
4  2004             3       2                7                6         1
5  2005             1       4                2                1         0
6  2006             5       5                1                3         3
7  2007             1       2                4                1         5
8  2008             1       3                4                5         4
```

[image: My Plot]

I was expecting the graph having the correct x-axis values.
Right now it displays the plot but the years on the x-axis is are plotted with 2 intervals
2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008

Comment: What happens if you leave out `width=0.4`?

Comment: @Barmar no changes still has the same interval on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote in your code, you can use `seaborn` to do this task.

```
sn.barplot(topics_df,x='Year',y='Sexeducation',color='b')
plt.show()
```

And this is gonna be the output :

[image]

If you insist on using matplotlib, then you can set xticks by passing Year to it.

```
plt.bar(topics_df.Year, topics_df.Sexeducation, color="blue", width=0.4)
plt.xticks(topics_df.Year)
plt.show()
```

The output of this code will be :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. I tried both ideas and they worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.xticks([2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008])`

Comment: Including an explanation why this should be used is very helpful.

Comment: Using plt.xticks() ot plt.gca().set_xticks() you can explicitly set the ticks of the x axis. It receives a list or array of values. You can set the values explicitly or get them from your dataset like np.unique(topics_df["year"])

Answer (score 0):

You can set the specific ticks based on your years data (i.e. the `"Year"` data column). Keep in mind that the more ticks you have the more cluttered your axes will be.

If you decide you want to, you can add this line after plotting:

```py
plt.gca().set_xticks(topics_df.Year)
```

`plt.gca()` gets the current axes (you could also just to `plt.xticks(...)`, but I prefer this way) and `set_xticks` will set which x-ticks to include in the plot.

Comment: thank you for the solution. and just asking is their any advantage on using the
``plt.gca().set_xticks()`` rather than using plt.xsticks() for the Year values.

Comment: No specific advantage. I just generally prefer `Axes` interface (see [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html) and [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces) to see the two options, specifically [this part](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit) on why you might want to use one of the other).